# How does Python's super() work without call directly?

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm on Python and I'm checking and comparing my understanding with ready-made code on the internet. I'm familiar with the concepts of inheritance but I ran into some code [here](https://github.com/nywang16/Pixel2Mesh/blob/930a016b3e80713bb61c3671bee3ecfe5bce6c49/p2m/layers.py#L239) that confused me!

Although it uses inheritance, I don't understand where it calls the _call function! These functions seem to be called and executed somewhere other than user code.Can someone help me understand it؟

a simple example of inheritance :

```
class one(object):
  def __init__(self,a,b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b

  def _call(self):
    return self.a + self.b

class two(one):
  def __init__(self,a,b,c):
    super(two,self).__init__(a,b)
    self.c = c

  def _call_(self):
    print(self.c * self.c)
```

used super() to call the **init**() of the One class

```
mt = two(1,2,3)
print(mt._call())
```

Comment: `two` has the `_call` method from its parent class. Notice that both classes have different underscores in the `call`, which makes them different methods.

Comment: Is the spelling (```_call```/```_call_```) intentional?

Comment: Note, that `two` has a method `_call_` with trailing underscore. `one` has a method `_call` without that, and that method is used later.

Comment: In the original code, `_call` is invoked by the base class implementation of `__call__` (the method invoked when the function call operator is invoked on an object). In your code `_call` is indeed not used anywhere, and there is further confusion between `_call` (a "protected" method that the code has invented), `__call__` (the special method invoked for the function call operator), and `_call_` (possibly a misspelling of one of the above).

Comment: @user4815162342 thank you for your answer. my question is about the original code. Is the `__call__` function [here][1] in the original code executed by calling the Layer class?
  
[1]: https://github.com/nywang16/Pixel2Mesh/blob/930a016b3e80713bb61c3671bee3ecfe5bce6c49/p2m/layers.py#L112

Comment: @shayanHojati Yes, subclasses of `Layer` all inherit its implementation of `__call__`.

Comment: @user4815162342 I'm so sorry for so many questions. I change class two to this:
    ```def __call__(self):
      print(self.c)```
in my code :
I expected when creating `mt` object from the class `two`, the function `__call__` be called such as `__init__` function(Builder)! but it didn't happen! (So it seems that the `__call__` function needs to be called explicitly)
in original code:
So according to the conclusion of the paragraph above, the `__call__` function in the original code should be called somewhere. I don't see anywhere in the code explicitly calling the `__call __` function!

Comment: @shayanHojati It's not true that `__call__` has to be called explicitly, it will be automatically called through the function call operator, `obj()`. I don't fully understand what your code was or what you expected to happen. Maybe you are confusing construction (a call of the type, i.e. `obj = ClassName()`) with calling of the instance (i.e. `result = obj()`). It's hard to tell without seeing the full code, but please note that it should be posted as a separate question.

Comment: @user4815162342 thanks, I post that in a separate question.